# Is there any medical upside in using a sunscreen that isn't broad spectrum (i.e., protecting against UVA and UVB)?

Tags: sunscreen-sunblock

I read on 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ultraviolet_index:

> Because of the way the UV index is calculated, it technically expresses the risk of developing sunburn, which is caused mostly by UVB radiation. However, UVA radiation also causes damage (photoaging, melanoma[22]). Under some conditions, including most tanning beds which generate even higher UV intensities,[23][24][25] the UVA level may be disproportionately higher than described by the UV index. *The use of broad-spectrum (UVA/UVB) sunscreen can help address this concern.*

Is there any medical upside  in using a sunscreen that isn't broad spectrum (i.e., protecting against UVA and UVB)?

Comment: "Is there any point" seems like a bit of a strawman. Sure, there's a point. It's probably cheaper for the manufacturer to make. I think your question could be improved.

Comment: @CareyGregory thanks good point I have replaced it with "medical upside" to be more precise